# Calling native method from rest service

Tags: java, rest, java-native-interface, restlet

I am using restlet framework to create rest service that uses native library. I have tested my native library in simple java application. But when I try to load library (`libsomename.so` on Linux) inside rest service, library could not be found. Looks like environment variable `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` is not set for local rest engine inside restlet framework.I am calling main restlet application with enviroment variable set, but inside ServerResource I can't load library and I get `java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError` exception. Any idea what is wrong?

Comment: Could you tell us the way you use Restlet? As standalone or embedded within a servlet engine? Thanks very much!

Comment: I use Restlet as standalone.

Comment: if you are calling this native library from a server resource, you may have issue since the native library is already loaded. A new server resource is instantiated for each incoming request. Try to load this library statically.